# react - open dropdown will lead to container expanding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

This is the bar and dropdown not yet expanding.
[image]

When I expand the bar:
 [image]

it expands the container.

What I expect is 
[image]

Bad drawing but I think you got the idea.

`App`contain `<Bar/>` which contain `<Dropdown/>`

CodeSandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-johnson-3kmto?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CSS issue, your `.dropdown .dropdown__list` style is displaying as a block level element, which will affect its parent's size.

You can change the CSS for that selector to something like this:

```css
.dropdown .dropdown__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  /* New properties added below */
  position: absolute;      /* Position this out of the regular flow */
  z-index: 100000;         /* Dropdowns should usually overlap whatever is below them */
  width: 100%;             /* Match the width of its parent element */
  margin: 0;               /* Remove unwanted spacing */
  border: 1px solid grey;  /* Add a border to match its parent */
  border-top: none;        /* Optionally, remove the border between the options and their parent */
  left: -1px;              /* Offset by the thickness of the border so everything lines up */
  background: #fff;        /* Add a background */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following three lines to your style css will likely solve the problem.

```css
.dropdown .dropdown__list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Edit: Sorry, should have explained what is going on here. The property `position: absolute` will place the element relative to the closest parent element with `position: relative`. After that you can custimize the position by using the `top`, `left`, `right`,`bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

`.school { display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-height: 72px;}`

add max-height to your .school css properties

Answer (score 0):

Here is the the `Bar` component should be like:

```
import React from "react";

import ImageIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Image";
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

import "./styles.css";

function Bar(props) {
  const {
    fileTypes,
    handleTypeChange,
    selectedFileType,
    isTypeDropdownOpen,
    setIsTypeDropdownOpen
  } = props;
  return (
    <div
      className="school__bar school__filter-bar"
      style={{ position: "relative", height: "68px" }}
    >
      <div className="school__filter-bar__dropdown">
        <button className="school__filter-bar__dropdown__btn">
          <ImageIcon />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div
        className="school__filter-bar__section"
        style={{ position: "absolute", left: "38px" }}
      >
        <div className={"school__filter-bar__section__type"}>
          <Dropdown
            options={fileTypes}
            onOptionClick={handleTypeChange}
            currentOption={selectedFileType}
            isOpen={isTypeDropdownOpen}
            setIsOpen={setIsTypeDropdownOpen}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Bar;
```

Link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-brahmagupta-sbcl9?file=/src/App.js)